# Failures when trying to fill in a list

Tags: sqlite, qooxdoo

A few days ago I consulted about bugs when querying a sqlite and now I'm lost on how to incorporate the data provided by the sqlite query to a list in qooxdoo.

```
//variable=  [{"pajarillo": "comsan", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "eursco1", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "mutswa", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "blared1", "conteo": 8}, {"pajarillo": "carcro1", "conteo": 11}, {"pajarillo": "tawowl1", "conteo": 3}, {"pajarillo": "commoo3", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "houspa", "conteo": 16}, {"pajarillo": "humvoc", "conteo": 2}, {"pajarillo": "eurgol", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "whiwag", "conteo": 14}, {"pajarillo": "grywag", "conteo": 5}, {"pajarillo": "belmin1", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "eurbla", "conteo": 5}, {"pajarillo": "comchi1", "conteo": 4}, {"pajarillo": "rocpig", "conteo": 2}, {"pajarillo": "cowpig1", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "eurrob1", "conteo": 32}, {"pajarillo": "watrai1", "conteo": 1}, {"pajarillo": "firecr1", "conteo": 19}, {"pajarillo": "goldcr1", "conteo": 5}, {"pajarillo": "sonthr1", "conteo": 1}];

var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("Detectadas");
win.setWidth(300);
win.setHeight(200);
win.setShowMinimize(false);

var composite = new qx.ui.container.Composite();

    win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox( 5));
    
    win.setShowStatusbar(true);
    win.setStatus("Aves detectadas con BirdNet");
    win.open();

   var atom = new qx.ui.basic.Atom(
        "Listado de aves detectadas con BirdNet");


 var oneList = new qx.ui.form.List();
      oneList.set({ height: 280, width: 150, selectionMode: "one" });

const req = new qx.io.request.Xhr("http://__:8081/getData");
 req.send();

                  req.addListener("success", function(e) 
                  {
                    const resp = e.getTarget();
                    variable= resp.getResponse();
                    console.log(variable);
                    win.setStatus( "Consulta completada.");
                 
                    
                    oneList.set({ height: 280, width: 150, selectionMode: "one" });
                  
                    var tmp= [{ "pajarillo": "", "conteo": ""} ];
                    var model__lista_empresas = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel( tmp);
                    var controller__lista_empresas = new qx.data.controller.List( model__lista_empresas, oneList, "pajarillo", "conteo"); 
                    controller__lista_empresas.setModel( qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel( variable));
                   }, this);      
 /*
 var tmp= [{ "pajarillo": "", "conteo": ""} ];
        var model__lista_empresas = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel( tmp);
        var controller__lista_empresas = new qx.data.controller.List( model__lista_empresas, oneList, "pajarillo", "conteo"); 
    controller__lista_empresas.setModel( qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel( variable));
   */       
        
        
       
  
  win.add( composite);
  win.add( atom);
  win.add( oneList);
  
  



this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:20});
win.open()
```

The question is that if I copy and put as a variable the response from the data server (sqlite), in the list I can see the response list. But if I use the response from the server directly, I get error.

To say that I am a novice in this and I thank you for your patience.

Best regards.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

I've given it a lot of thought but not the right one, it's clear. If you can help me I thank you.

Comment: Hello,

Well I think I found the cause, the data array in javascript was represented as a string.

I just passed it through JSON.parse(..) and that was it.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what a server send you. As I remember python server send you string. And another thing please try to describe more accurate and shorter your questions because its to difficult read whole stuff. Only code which probably cause problem without code which doesn't effect. Without comments and empty lines too. Your question will be disapproved by other readers.